# Base class for view with RazorGenerator precompiled views

Tags: c#, razor, msbuild, razorgenerator

I have console project with some `.cshtml` files stored in `Resources` folder, which is built into `.cs` files with `Razorgenerator.MsBuild` nuget package.

I need to replace `WebViewPage` view base class for generated view, but adding web.config file with `pageBaseType="ConsoleApp.MyViewBase"` option set or changing location of files in different ways did not help me and no any other ways where found.

View class is always generated as:

```
public partial class _Resources_Index_cshtml : 
         System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<ConsoleApp.ModelClass> { ... }
```

Hope, there is some way to confgure the class globally for all views, without adding directives at the beginning of every `.cshtml` file.

Comment: Please explain your overall aim a bit more clearly? There may be a better alternative to changing your view base class.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, am just need to setup custom properties for current class of view for using them in razor code and also need to render the view into a string.

Comment: So this is some sort of command-line HTML page generator?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yeap. Am also using that msbuild task to be able to debug views. Now am on way of remaking this nuget package and if no answers will help me, I post my mork here with link to modified package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that that setting base view in `web.config` works in latest RazorGenerator.

So update your RazorGenerator package and try to have something like this in `web.config`:

```
<configSections>    
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="WebApplication2.Views.BaseView2">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />        
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

In my case I was adding precompilation (with RazorGenerator.Mvc and RazorGenerator.MsBuild packages) to old project and it didn't work. The problem was that I had `Version=2.0.0.0` in my `configSections` project and had to change it to `Version=3.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds it helpful, there is a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.MsBuild.CustomViewBase/) for this by me. It is same Razorgenerator.MsBuild but with replacing `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` by `Custom.System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`. So if you want to use custom WebViewPage, install the package and add you class named WebViewPage in namespace Custom.System.Web.Mvc. Like:

```
namespace Custom.System.Web.Mvc
{
    public abstract class WebViewPage<T>
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope, some not so dumb solution or standard option exists.

Comment: @Marius, hi. Source code is probably outdated. So better ill describe all my changes: clone razor repo from https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator and change RazorGenerator.MsBuild\RazorGenerator.cs by replacing `string result = host.GenerateCode();` with `string result = host.GenerateCode().Replace("System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<", "Custom.System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<");`

Comment: Am also working with aspnet 5 and strongly belive, it will allow me to make much more things.

Comment: I tested the latest version of RazorGenerator locally, at it now supports custom base classes. I didn't get it to work using the nuget package, so it might be something not published yet